# Hide an application's dock icon

Tags: macos, icons, dock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show/Hide Application Icon in Dock](https://superuser.com/questions/217649/show-hide-application-icon-in-dock)

Is there any way to keep an application from displaying an icon in the dock on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the way mentioned in the [linked topic](https://superuser.com/questions/217649/show-hide-application-icon-in-dock), i.e. you will lose your application menu and the entry in the Cmd-Tab application switcher. The behavior is similar to all applications that allow you to do this via a preference, you never get a menu without a Dock icon.