# Hide VirtualBox in Dock when launching Vagrant

Tags: macos, virtualbox, vagrant

I upgraded my VirtualBox to 5.1 a while ago, and now whenever I run `vagrant up` the VirtualBox icon shows up in my Dock. This was not the behaviour I had in VirtualBox 5.0 (or so I remember).

How can I hide this icon without having to [edit anything](https://superuser.com/questions/217649/show-hide-application-icon-in-dock)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and it lasted months! It appears to have been some kind of bug with either Virtualbox or Vagrant. I was on Vagrant version 1.9.1 and Virtualbox 5.1.19 (I think). Upgrading to the latest of each of those should fix your problem.

As of this writing Vagrant is version 1.9.7 and Virtualbox is 5.1.22.